# Shuffle rows of a DataFrame until all consecutive values in a column are different?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, recursion

I have a dataframe with rows that I'd like to shuffle continuously until the value in column `B` is not identical across any two consecutive rows:

initial dataframe:

```
A  |  B
_______
a     1
b     1
c     2
d     3
e     3
```

Possible outcome:

```
A  |  B
_______
b     1
c     2
e     3
a     1
d     3
```

I made a function `scramble` meant to do this but I am having trouble passing the newly scrambled dataframe back into the function to test for matching `B` values:

```
def scamble(x):
    curr_B='nothing'
    for index, row in x.iterrows():
        next_B=row['B']
        if str(next_B) == str(curr_B):
            x=x.sample(frac=1)
            curr_B=next_B
        curr_B=next_B
    return x
df=scramble(df)
```

I suspect the function is finding the matching values in the next row, but I can't shuffle it continuously until there are no two sequential rows with the same `B` value.

Printing the output yields a dataframe shows consecutive rows with the same value in `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to eliminate consecutive duplicates, you can just use `groupby` and `cumcount`, then reindex your DataFrame:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('B').cumcount().sort_values().index]

   A  B
0  a  1
2  c  2
3  d  3
1  b  1
4  e  3
```

---

If you actually want randomness, then you can group on `cumcount` and call `shuffle`. This should eliminate consecutive dupes to some degree (NOT GUARANTEED) while preserving randomness and still avoiding slow iteration. Here's an example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
(df.groupby(df.groupby('B').cumcount(), group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1))
   .reset_index(drop=True))

   A  B
0  d  3
1  a  1
2  c  2
3  b  1
4  e  3
```

Comment: Your first solution doesn't quite work if the number of dupes isn't well balanced, e.g. if `'B'` is `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @root good point. This would need some corner case handling. I was hoping OP would weigh the tradeoffs in performance and correctness.

Comment: thanks @cs95  the second solution works great. I have a follow up that hopefully makes sense: Suppose I have column `C` and it's `[5,4,3,3,5]`. I want to find the sequence of rows that reduce consecutive dupes for `B` all the while trying to keep `C` as sequential as possible. Is such a thing possible? Thanks for the assist. I've tried attaching `sort_values(by='C')` to the solution, but no avail.

Comment: @machump wow, that's a pretty complicated problem. I don't know what the solution will look like. I don't think this solution will scale to meet that additional constraint. Try opening a new question under the python tag to get more focused answers.

Comment: thanks @cs95. I'll make a new question after deeper research. Your solution is very good progress compared to  what I was starting with.